# jQuery is first and not first in same line, possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery to append a column to a table

```
jQuery('#tb tr:first').append('<td>manufacturer_part_number</td>');
```

This will append first `<tr>`'s `<td>` to the table, but I also want to assign a different td for while the `<td>` is not first  child, can I do something like this?

```
jQuery('#tb tr:first').append(
    '<td>manufacturer</td>'
).not(
    '#tb tr:first'
).append(
    '<td>&nbsp</td>'
);
```

If not possible, are there any ways to do with minimum code?

Comment: put html code .

Answer (score 1):

Nope, when you select the first row, you can't chain on that element as if it were the entire table, you have to do it seperately

```
jQuery('#tb tr:first').append('<td>manufacturer_part_number</td>');
jQuery('#tb tr:not(:first)').append('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
```

You could of course select the table first, and then go back with `end()`

```
jQuery('#tb').find('tr:first').append('<td>manufacturer</td>').end()
             .find('tr:not(:first)').append('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
```

Or use `append()` with a callback

```
jQuery('#tb tr').append(function(i) {
    return $('<td />', { text : i === 0 ? 'manufacturer' : '&nbsp;' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should loop the other rows

```
$('#tb tr:first').append('<td>manufacturer_part_number</td>');
$('#tb tr:not(:first)').each(function() {
   $(this).append('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
});
```

Comment: `#tb tr:not(:first`this selector is wrong guy. You forget to close it.

Comment: Thank you, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [**next()**](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [**end()**](https://api.jquery.com/end/)

```
jQuery('#tb').find('tr:first').append('<td>manufacturer</td>').end().find('tr:first').next().append('<td>&nbsp</td>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this way:

```
$('#tb tr').each(function(i) {
  if(i===0){
    $(this).append('<td>manufacturer_part_number</td>');
  } else {
    $(this).append('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
  }
});
```